# Visual Studio post-build event macros are empty

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 (or 2015), I have a particular project that in the post-build event, I'm trying to pass $(TargetDir) to a batch file.

The problem is, all the macros are empty, except for the macros beginning in "Solution".  Also, all the macros are shown correctly in the "Edit Post-build Event Command line" dialog.

Example

```
echo ConfigurationName is "$(ConfigurationName)"
```

Results in

```
Configuration name is ""
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same problem.
According to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/179716e8-89eb-40ff-ba13-339e2d25d1c8/outdir-and-targetpath-macros-are-empty?forum=msbuild, you have to delete the `PropertyGroup` in the csproj file, and then to add the build event in Visual Studio again.
[image]

After you add it again, it will be at the end of the csproj file, and the macros should work.

Comment: I found this same issue in VS2015

Comment: I had the same issue. I had added PropertyGroup it manually in csproj file. I had to delete it and added it again from project properties > Build Events tab and it started working. Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: I spent so much time troubleshooting this using msbuild on 2017. The critical point here should be that there is a [bug?](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1569) with the .NET SDK that requires the `<PostBuildEvent>` to come after the `<Import>` and `<Target>` elements in the csproj file.

Comment: I manually edited the csproj and moved the   <PropertyGroup> section to the very bottom, just above the </Project> tag, and that worked.

Comment: It might be this bug report also: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/677

Comment: Or this one https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/2367 or this one https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1569, I can't tell.

Comment: JetBrain's Rider IDE is also affected by this.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem when migrating a project file from old .NET framework format to SDK style.

It seems the structure of the PostBuildEvent changed and is not converted by the "upgrade assistant" tool.

This was the command before:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>echo ProjectDir: $(ProjectDir)</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is the new version:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="echo ProjectDir: $(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

To do the migration: open the code file (right click on project, "Properties"). Then cut the post build snippet and save the file. Paste the snippet again - now it should have the new format.

Answer (score 3):

Try $(Configuration) instead of $(ConfigurationMode), I was having this issue too and this solved it, although I don't know why it happens...

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was just to make sure that the post build event was the very last thing in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. This seems to happen when I have multiple instances of VS open. Try closing all instances or VS and starting up one.

Answer (score 0):

Curiously this can still be 'a thing' with VS2022 (though possibly only Preview 17.4.x). I have several .NET Framework projects that can't load their build events unless they are in the old format and can't save them at all.