# Visual Studio $(ProjectDir) is empty string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I want to add a post-build command. when I go to 'Macros' window I see the correct path coresponging to $(ProjectDir) variable. So I added the command:

> $(ProjectDir)ClientApp\npm run build

but when I execute build I get the following error:

> The command 'ClientApp\npm run build'exited with code 3.

I change MSBuild verbose to Diagnose and in the Output window I saw:

> 1>Target "PostBuildEvent" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets":
>   1>  Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core,
>   Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
>   1>  Task "Exec" 1>    Task
>   Parameter:WorkingDirectory=bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ 1>    Task
>   Parameter:Command=ClientApp\npm run build 1>    ClientApp\npm run
>   build 1>    The system cannot find the path specified. 1>
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4933,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "ClientApp\npm run build" exited with code
>   3. 1>  Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.

In the targets file I got these lines:

```
  <Target
      Name="PostBuildEvent"
      Condition="'$(PostBuildEvent)' != '' and ('$(RunPostBuildEvent)' != 'OnOutputUpdated' or '$(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile)' != '$(_AssemblyTimestampAfterCompile)')"
      DependsOnTargets="$(PostBuildEventDependsOn)">

    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)" />

  </Target>
```

Can I change the working dir from $(OutDir) to $(ProjectDir) and how?

Any ideas where I am mistaken? 
NB - I added the command in a BAT file, just to test but the result was the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio post-build event macros are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748846/visual-studio-post-build-event-macros-are-empty)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) instead

Comment: The question is why $(ProjectDir) is empty?

Comment: $(ProjectDir) seems to be correct inside targets(`AfterTargets="BeforeBuild"`), but not at "root level" properties. For those cases $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) works well

Comment: I would guess because it occurs before `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`. Putting it /behind/ that Import solved problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

The problem could affect other VS variable as well.
The universal solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748846/visual-studio-post-build-event-macros-are-empty).

Comment: Dumbest bug ever. How is this not fixed after all this time.