# Pre- Post- Build Event Variables in Visual Studio are Empty

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, post-build-event, pre-build-event, build-events

Have a .NET Core app that I'm trying to use $(ProjectDir) with and when I attempt to pass in that macro, I get an empty value. I tried what was suggested in [Issue 26748846](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748846/visual-studio-2013-post-build-event-macros-are-empty), but that didn't seem to solve my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in .NET Core projects, the pre- and post build macros are set too early and the `$(ProjectDir)` property is not yet available. Note that pre- and post build macros are deprecated and should be replaced by proper targets (see https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1569).

A quick fix would be to replace `$(ProjectDir)` with `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\`.

Comment: Splitting the ProjectGroup and adding the targets import in between solved my issue. I wish the .NET Core project would just do that out of the box. Thanks for the GitHub issue link!